# MonoGame: Load SoundEffect from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, audio, stream, load, monogame

I figured I'd put all the .wav files into one file and then load them. I don't think it will be a problem but something is wrong.

It reads the .wav file from the disk and then, using BinaryWriter, writes it to a file like this:

```
using (var fs = File.Create("sounds"))
{
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        var data = File.ReadAllBytes("test.wav");
        bw.Write(data.Length);
        bw.Write(data);
    }
}
```

Then I try to load it using the static method SoundEffect.FromStream like this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead("sounds"))
    {
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            var length = br.ReadInt32();
            var data = br.ReadBytes(length);
            ms.Write(data);
        }
    }

    var sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(ms);
}
```

And then I get an exception: "Specified stream is not a wave file.".
Can someone help me with this or explain why I can't do it this way?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Seek position to the beginning of the MemoryStream before reading?

Comment: I set the Seek position to the beginning of the MemoryStream before reading as you advised and it works. Thanks. `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set the Seek position back to the beginning of the stream before reading, as you have already commented! :)

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.seek?view=net-8.0)